# Docker desktop crashing on windows 10

Tags: docker, crash, windows-10, named-pipes, docker-desktop

I am starting docker desktop on windows 10 but i am getting the following errors:

> Docker.Core.Backend.BackendDestroyException: One or more errors
>   occurred.    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.b__0()    at
>   Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()
>
> System.AggregateException:   One or more errors occurred.
>        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at Docker.Backend.LifecycleClient.DockerStart()
>        at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
>        at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
>
> ```
>  Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
>  unable to fetch daemon.json: Get http://unix/engine/daemon.json: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
> ```
>
> headers)
>           at Docker.Backend.HttpClientExtensions.d__2`1.MoveNext()
>        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>           at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>           at Docker.Backend.HttpClientExtensions.<GetJsonAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()

I uninstalled and then installed from fresh but again when i am running i still get this issue.

[image] I did reset to factory defaults but no use.

Comment: Are you using wsl? The error cannot connect to unix suggest me that but I need confirmation. May be your Linux image is broken

Comment: @Martindosantos do santos  Ya i am using wsl. How can i repair my linux image?

Comment: First of all, check if wsl is working. then, you can install another image of ubuntu or bebian, and associate wsl with another image. Another thing, are you using wsl2 (preview) ?

Comment: @Martindosantos WSL is there: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>     Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
DisplayName      : Windows Subsystem for Linux
Description      : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
RestartRequired  : Required
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :

Comment: @Martindosantos can you guide on this "you can install another image of ubuntu or bebian, and associate wsl with another image. "

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#versions-earlier-than-windows-10-version-1903